# Apply from date & to date filter while getting Lead Activities in marketo

Tags: marketo

I want to integrate MARKETO api in my .net project. I want to retrieve lead activities based on from date & to date parameter but when I call Lead Activities method is return all activities.
Is there any way to add from date & to date parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The Since Date for Get Lead Activities is represented by a [paging token](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-paging-token/).  There is no end date, you just stop retrieving activities when you have one which is greater than your desired end date.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I want to retrieve Lead Activites between some data for ex. from 3-mar-2016 to 08-Mar-2016..
it is possible or not?

Comment: You'll want to get a paging token with a sinceDatetime of your earliest date, and then page through the set until you retrieve data from your latest desired time.